# Looping based on user input is not working, it just loops infinitely

Tags: c, loops

I am working on a game, and I have to give the user the ability to place "penguins" on tiles on a game board. The amount of penguins per player is declared a `num_pengwings`, however when I create a for loop that's supposed to break when not `x < num_pengwings`, but it doesn't break... anyone know how I can fix this?

Below is what I tried, and I was expecting it to loop through each player, and ask them to place their penguins, for however many penguins the user input earlier. Is there something wrong with this function, maybe I messed up the do while loop?

```
void placePenguins(struct board *gameBoard, Player players[], int num_players, int num_pengwings) {
    int i, x, peng_row, peng_column;
       int tileOccupied[gameBoard->rows][gameBoard->columns];

    for (int row = 0; row < gameBoard->rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < gameBoard->columns; col++) {
            tileOccupied[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
        for (x = 0; x < num_pengwings; x++) {
            do {
                printf("Enter which row & column you would like to place penguin %d at: ", x+1);
                scanf("%d %d", &peng_row, &peng_column);

                if (gameBoard->tiles[(peng_row-1) * gameBoard->columns + (peng_column-1)] == 0) {
                    printf("You can't place penguins on a water spot.\n");
                    
                } else if (gameBoard->tiles[(peng_row-1) * gameBoard->columns + (peng_column-1)] > 0 && tileOccupied[peng_row-1][peng_column-1] == 1) {
                    printf("You can't place your penguin there.\n");
                } else {
                    players[i].fish += gameBoard->tiles[(peng_row-1) * gameBoard->columns + (peng_column-1)];
                    tileOccupied[peng_row-1][peng_column-1] = 1;
                    printf("Penguin %d placed.\n", x+1);
                    
                }

                
            } while (gameBoard->tiles[(peng_row-1) * gameBoard->columns + (peng_column-1)] == 0 || tileOccupied[peng_row-1][peng_column-1] == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); As well as [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Note: you really should check the return value from `scanf` which must be `2`. Better yet, use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` which will make it far, far easier to untangle bad input.

Comment: OT: The 2D array `int tileOccupied[][];` is local to the function you've shown and it will evaporate when that function ends. Hope you're planning some solution to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

The `for` loops are not the problem. The `do while` is. The `do while` will repeat if either `gameBoard->tiles[(peng_row-1) * gameBoard->columns + (peng_column-1)] == 0` is true OR `tileOccupied[peng_row-1][peng_column-1] == 1` is true.

If you check all the paths of the `if else` statements, they will all result in one of these being true. For the first `if`, the first condition will already be true and the loop will repeat. For the next `else if`, then the second condition will already be true and the loop will repeat. Presumably these first 2 are expected because you want to repeat if an error occurs.

However, for the 3rd `else`, you are setting `tileOccupied[peng_row-1][peng_column-1] = 1;` and then checking `tileOccupied[peng_row-1][peng_column-1] == 1` in the `do while` loop condition so that will always cause the loop to repeat.

I would suggest you manually break the loop instead:

```
for (;;) {
    printf("Enter which row & column you would like to place penguin %d at: ", x+1);
    scanf("%d %d", &peng_row, &peng_column);

    if (gameBoard->tiles[(peng_row-1) * gameBoard->columns + (peng_column-1)] == 0) {
        printf("You can't place penguins on a water spot.\n");
        
    } else if (gameBoard->tiles[(peng_row-1) * gameBoard->columns + (peng_column-1)] > 0 && tileOccupied[peng_row-1][peng_column-1] == 1) {
        printf("You can't place your penguin there.\n");
    } else {
        players[i].fish += gameBoard->tiles[(peng_row-1) * gameBoard->columns + (peng_column-1)];
        tileOccupied[peng_row-1][peng_column-1] = 1;
        printf("Penguin %d placed.\n", x+1);
        break;
    }
}
```